# How to get all employees who may or may not have ParentID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

```
IEnumerable<ViewEmployees> employees = from e in db.Users
                                       join p in db.Users on e.ParentID equals p.Id
                                       select new ViewEmployees
                                                  {
                                                       EmployeeName = e.Name,
                                                       EmployeeID = e.Id,
                                                       EmployeeCode = e.UserName,
                                                       ParentID = e.ParentID,
                                                       ParentName = p.Name
                                                  };
```

This query is written to pick the name of parent and shows all the employees..

It shows only the employee how have parent Id..

I want both who have `parentId` and who don't...

Answer (score 0):

The first step in producing a left outer join of two collections is to perform an inner join by using a group join. (See How to: Perform Inner Joins (C# Programming Guide) for an explanation of this process.) In this example, the list of Person objects is inner-joined to the list of Pet objects based on a Person object that matches Pet.Owner.
The second step is to include each element of the first (left) collection in the result set even if that element has no matches in the right collection. This is accomplished by calling DefaultIfEmpty on each sequence of matching elements from the group join. In this example, DefaultIfEmpty is called on each sequence of matching Pet objects. The method returns a collection that contains a single, default value if the sequence of matching Pet objects is empty for any Person object, thereby ensuring that each Person object is represented in the result collection.

```
public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
    {
        Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
        Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
        Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
        Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

        Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
        Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
        Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
        Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
        Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

        // Create two lists.
        List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
        List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

        var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };

        foreach (var v in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.FirstName + ":", v.PetName);
        }
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: It is a self Join..
means one emplooyee has one parentId (Which is also an Employee)@Oscar

Comment: @user3409375 The same principles applies. The trick is in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent `User` in a temporary variable `parent` like so:

```
var employees = from e in db.Users
     let parent = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => e.ParentID == p.Id)
     select new ViewEmployees
     {
         EmployeeName = e.Name,
         EmployeeID = e.Id,
         EmployeeCode = e.UserName,
         ParentID = e.ParentID,
         ParentName = parent.Name
     };
```

You don't need to check for `parent != null` because the statement is translated into SQL, which is not troubled by null values.

It would even be easier if `User` had a navigation property `Parent`.

Comment: it shows an error on ""FirstOrdefault""
could not be found...@Gert Arnold